# One of my assignment question - Just looking to keep it simple

Tags: python

> The program will take one argument, corresponding to one of the
> relations' keys. The program will print out the statement:
>
> John, I am your x
>
> Where x = the relationship.
>
> For example, if the argument is "Lisa", it should print "John, I am your
> sister"
>
> If the key is "Smith" you should instead print "No, I am your father"

Here is my code:

```
def Relation(name):

    name = str(sys.argv[1])

    relations = {'Smith':'father', 'Lisa':'sister', 'Han':'brother in law',\
     'R2D2':'droid', 'Rey':'Padawan', 'Tatooine':'homeworld'}

    if name == 'Darth Vader':
        print("No, I am your father")

    else:
        print("John, i am your %s"%(relations[key]))

Relation()
```

I'm getting an error in this code: `missing 1 required positional argument` - what am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing... 1 required positional argument - `Relation()`, what about `name`?

Comment: relation expects a parameter `name` but you are just calling `Relation()` without any parameter. However it's not clear why it needs a parameter since instead of using it it reads it from `sys.argv[1]`. So probably you just need to make Relation a parameter-free function, or read name outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not import `sys` module, and you also need to specify the argument for the function `Relation`.

```
def Relation(name):
    try:
        relations = {'Smith':'father', 'Lisa':'sister', 'Han':'brother in law',\
         'R2D2':'droid', 'Rey':'Padawan', 'Tatooine':'homeworld'}

        if name == 'Darth Vader':
            print("No, I am your father")

        else:
            print("John, i am your %s"%(relations[name]))
    except KeyError:
        print("Key does not exists")


import sys
name = str(sys.argv[1])

Relation(name)
```

Added an excpetion handler, thanks to sembei norimaki's comment.

Comment: name="Chewbacca"  -> Unhandled Exception

Comment: Thanks - I tried the recommended change - gives me another error-expected indented block

Comment: @iwrestledthebeartwice should be ```name = str(sys.argv[1])``` be ```name = str(input())```? Otherwise I believe it will end up with error.

Comment: @Blaco OP included `sys.argv[1]` and mentioned that it is an assignment. According to that, he will take input from the command line, and that's why I did not change the `sys.argv[]` to `input()`

Comment: @PrashantPawar alright, what error did you get? Is it list index out of range?

Comment: @iwrestledthebeartwice - Do you see any issue with the if statement? assuming I have already changed the key to 'Smith' instead of Darth Vader'- giving an error but working well on else

Comment: @PrashantPawar I did not understand you, If you change the `Darth Vader` to `Smith` then the control will never go to the `else` block and will execute whatever is in the `if` block. If you have an error, please mention it, or ask a new question with the modified code on SO.